# Node: Writing a base64 source to an image file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I'm working on a node app with a file input that uses client side js to get the base64 dataURI code from an image and send it to the server as a socket message.

the resultant base64 message is in the format:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QCcRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAA ...
```

On the node/server side, I want to save this message as an image file:

```
    fs.writeFile(newFilePath, src, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('It\'s saved! ' + entryID + '.' + fileType + '\n');
      socket.emit('sendFileSuccess', entryID + '\n');
    });
```

After running, the file does save to the right location with a similar file size. But the file isn't a valid image when I open it up with preview ("It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.")

I'm looking for the minimum solution, and I'd plan to add any required complexity later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to take out the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part.

```
var data = src.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,'');

fs.writeFile(newFilePath, data, 'base64', function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved! ' + entryID + '.' + fileType + '\n');
  socket.emit('sendFileSuccess', entryID + '\n');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image back to binary format if you want to store it on your server as a proper image file.
To do this you need to parse and remove the base64 header "data:image/jpeg;base64,",
create a [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) with encoding set to "base64" and store it in the filesystem with the apropiate file extension parsed from the header.